# More threads added then slower OPENMP code

Tags: fortran, openmp

I tried to parallel a piece of code with OPENMP, but with increasing the number of processors, the code runs slower.!

**call OMP_set_num_threads(1)-->16.7sec**

**call OMP_set_num_threads(4)-->17.7sec**

**call OMP_set_num_threads(8)-->19sec**

System SPEC

Intel Corei7 3610QM 2.3GH up to 3.2GH with 4 cores and 8 threads
///8GB ram DDR3

```
call OMP_set_num_threads(8)
!$omp parallel 
!$omp do private(k,i,j,r,epsilonxx,epsilonyy,epsilonxy,epsilonzz,epsilonxz,&
 epsilonyz)  reduction(+:dr)

    do k=1,niac
      i = pair_i(k)
      j = pair_j(k)
    dx(1) = x(1,j) - x(1,i)
        dr  = dx(1)*dx(1)

    do d=2,dim
        dx(d) = x(d,j) - x(d,i)
        dr    = dr + dx(d)*dx(d)

    enddo

    r = sqrt(dr)

       do d=1,dim
        dvx(d) = vx(d,j) - vx(d,i)
       enddo


 if (dim.eq.3) then
      if((abs(itype(i)).gt.1000 .and. abs(itype(j)).gt.1000 ) ) then
      epsilonxx  =  dvx(1)*dwdx(1,k)
      epsilonyy  =  dvx(2)*dwdx(2,k)
      epsilonxy  =  (1/2.)*(dvx(1)*dwdx(2,k)+dvx(2)*dwdx(1,k))
      epsilonzz  =  dvx(dim)*dwdx(dim,k)
      epsilonxz  =  (1/2.)*(dvx(1)*dwdx(dim,k)+dvx(dim)*dwdx(1,k))
      epsilonyz  =  (1/2.)*(dvx(2)*dwdx(dim,k)+dvx(dim)*dwdx(2,k))

       epsxx(i) = epsxx(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxx/rho(j)
       epsxx(j) = epsxx(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxx/rho(i)
       epsyy(i) = epsyy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyy/rho(j)
       epsyy(j) = epsyy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyy/rho(i)
       epsxy(i) = epsxy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxy/rho(j)
       epsxy(j) = epsxy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxy/rho(i)
           epszz(i) = epszz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonzz/rho(j)
           epszz(j) = epszz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonzz/rho(i)
           epsxz(i) = epsxz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxz/rho(j)
           epsxz(j) = epsxz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxz/rho(i)
           epsyz(i) = epsyz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyz/rho(j)
           epsyz(j) = epsyz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyz/rho(i)


  elseif( (abs(itype(i)).lt.1000 ) .and. (abs(itype(j)).gt.1000 )  ) then


      epsilonxx_interface(i)  =(2/3.)*(2.e0*dvx(1)*dwdx(1,k) 
      epsilonxx_interface(j)  =dvx(1)*dwdx(1,k)
      epsilonyy_interface(i)  =(2/3.)*(2.e0*dvx(2)*dwdx(2,k)     
      epsilonyy_interface(j)  =dvx(2)*dwdx(2,k) 
      epsilonxy_interface(i)  =dvx(1)*dwdx(2,k) + dvx(2)*dwdx(1,k)  
      epsilonxy_interface(j)  =(1/2.)*(dvx(1)*dwdx(2,k)+dvx(2)*dwdx(1,k)) 
      epsilonzz_interface(i)  =(2/3.)*(2.e0*dvx(dim)*dwdx(dim,k)
      epsilonzz_interface(j)  =dvx(dim)*dwdx(dim,k)                  epsilonxz_interface(i)   =dvx(1)*dwdx(dim,k) + dvx(dim)*dwdx(1,k)              
      epsilonxz_interface(j)  =(1/2.)*(dvx(1)*dwdx(dim,k)+dvx(dim)*dwdx(1,k))   
      epsilonyz_interface(i)  =dvx(2)*dwdx(dim,k) + dvx(dim)*dwdx(2,k)  
      epsilonyz_interface(j)  =(1/2.)*(dvx(2)*dwdx(dim,k)+dvx(dim)*dwdx(2,k)) 


               epsxx(i) = epsxx(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxx_interface(i)/rho(j)
       epsxx(j) = epsxx(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxx_interface(j)/rho(i)
       epsyy(i) = epsyy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyy_interface(i)/rho(j)
       epsyy(j) = epsyy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyy_interface(j)/rho(i)
       epsxy(i) = epsxy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxy_interface(i)/rho(j)
       epsxy(j) = epsxy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxy_interface(j)/rho(i)
           epszz(i) = epszz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonzz_interface(i)/rho(j)
           epszz(j) = epszz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonzz_interface(j)/rho(i)
           epsxz(i) = epsxz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxz_interface(i)/rho(j)
           epsxz(j) = epsxz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxz_interface(j)/rho(i)
           epsyz(i) = epsyz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyz_interface(i)/rho(j)
           epsyz(j) = epsyz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyz_interface(j)/rho(i)

    elseif( (abs(itype(i)).gt.1000 ) .and. (abs(itype(j)).lt.1000 ) ) then

      epsilonxx_interface(j)  = (2/3.)*(2.e0*dvx(1)*dwdx(1,k)      
      epsilonxx_interface(i)  =dvx(1)*dwdx(1,k)
      epsilonyy_interface(j)  =(2/3.)*(2.e0*dvx(2)*dwdx(2,k) 
      epsilonyy_interface(i)  = dvx(2)*dwdx(2,k) 
      epsilonxy_interface(j)  =dvx(1)*dwdx(2,k) + dvx(2)*dwdx(1,k)  
      epsilonxy_interface(i)  = (1/2.)*(dvx(1)*dwdx(2,k)+dvx(2)*dwdx(1,k)) 
      epsilonzz_interface(j)  = (2/3.)*(2.e0*dvx(dim)*dwdx(dim,k) 
      epsilonzz_interface(i)  =dvx(dim)*dwdx(dim,k)   
      epsilonxz_interface(j)  =dvx(1)*dwdx(dim,k) + dvx(dim)*dwdx(1,k)              
      epsilonxz_interface(i)  =(1/2.)*(dvx(1)*dwdx(dim,k)+dvx(dim)*dwdx(1,k))   
      epsilonyz_interface(j)  =dvx(2)*dwdx(dim,k) + dvx(dim)*dwdx(2,k)  
      epsilonyz_interface(i)  =(1/2.)*(dvx(2)*dwdx(dim,k)+dvx(dim)*dwdx(2,k))  

       epsxx(i) = epsxx(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxx_interface(i)/rho(j)
       epsxx(j) = epsxx(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxx_interface(j)/rho(i)
       epsyy(i) = epsyy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyy_interface(i)/rho(j)
       epsyy(j) = epsyy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyy_interface(j)/rho(i)
       epsxy(i) = epsxy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxy_interface(i)/rho(j)
       epsxy(j) = epsxy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxy_interface(j)/rho(i)
   epszz(i) = epszz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonzz_interface(i)/rho(j)
   epszz(j) = epszz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonzz_interface(j)/rho(i)
   epsxz(i) = epsxz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxz_interface(i)/rho(j)
   epsxz(j) = epsxz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxz_interface(j)/rho(i)
   epsyz(i) = epsyz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyz_interface(i)/rho(j)
   epsyz(j) = epsyz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyz_interface(j)/rho(i)

      endif

   endif
enddo    
!$omp end do nowait
 endif
    !$omp end parallel
```

Comment: Sir , i do not understand what i should do! edit my answer? which one?

Comment: Please, try to edit your question to improve it (for instance provide a better code indentation and possibly a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Sir, i tried my best to SSCE my Question

Comment: Sir, i tried my best to SSCE my Question

Comment: http://www.compunity.org/training/tutorials/4%20OpenMP_and_Performance.pdf

Comment: @raxman: very useful reference, hope OP studies it carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much Dear raxman,.. God bless you in your all life!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance problem that you observe comes from the very foundation of the algorithm that you use. Each thread picks a pair of particles and computes some values, then modifies the value of `eps??` (where `??` is `xx`, `yy`, `zz`, etc.) for both particles. Depending on how the pair list is built, this could lead to many threads trying to modify the values for neighbouring particles or even for the same particle concurrently. In the former case it results in false sharing, which presents itself as huge slowdown due to cache lines being constantly invalidated and reloaded from higher level caches or from main memory. The latter results in completely wrong values for the array elements being computed.

While the latter problem can be easily fixed by either using atomic updates, e.g.

```
!$OMP ATOMIC UPDATE
epszz(i) = epszz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonzz_interface(i)/rho(j)
```

or `CRITICAL` constructs, e.g.

```
!$OMP CRITICAL
epsxx(i) = epsxx(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxx_interface(i)/rho(j)
epsxx(j) = epsxx(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxx_interface(j)/rho(i)
epsyy(i) = epsyy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyy_interface(i)/rho(j)
epsyy(j) = epsyy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyy_interface(j)/rho(i)
epsxy(i) = epsxy(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxy_interface(i)/rho(j)
epsxy(j) = epsxy(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxy_interface(j)/rho(i)
epszz(i) = epszz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonzz_interface(i)/rho(j)
epszz(j) = epszz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonzz_interface(j)/rho(i)
epsxz(i) = epsxz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonxz_interface(i)/rho(j)
epsxz(j) = epsxz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonxz_interface(j)/rho(i)
epsyz(i) = epsyz(i) + mass(j)*epsilonyz_interface(i)/rho(j)
epsyz(j) = epsyz(j) + mass(i)*epsilonyz_interface(j)/rho(i)
!$OMP END CRITICAL
```

or even array reductions, e.g.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL REDUCTION(+:epsxx,epsyy,epsxy,epszz,...)
```

the former problem requires that you change the algorithm. For example you can switch to a different pair list structure, e.g. an array of lists, where the array index is the particle number and each list contains the neighbours of that particle. Sorting the neighbour list will (kind of) reduce the false sharing. Depending on the geometry of the particle distribution, you might end up with severely unbalanced problem, therefore you should think about using dynamic loop scheduling.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Hristo Iliev, I'm much appriciated my friend thank you very very very much, God bless you

Comment: Dear Hristo Iliev, it seems that you are completely familiar with particle methods and more importantly the neighboring search in particles methods like SPH ! Very interesting

Comment: DEAR Hristo Iliev, when i use reduction for arrays, for example here REDUCTION(+:epsxx,epsyy,epsxy,epszz,...), the code crashes!I do not know why!! is it becuase of using Allocatable arrays??

Comment: Reduction makes a private copy of each argument. Allocatable arrays retain their allocation status, i.e. if they were allocated before the entry to the parallel region, then the private copies are automatically allocated with the same bounds as the original arrays. You might be running out of memory or your original array might not be properly allocated before the region. It could also be a compiler bug. Run your program within a debugger to see what is the case.